# Is “awfully well” an oxymoron?

Tags: oxymoron

The phrase “awfully well” is fairly common, but it strikes me as an oxymoron. Is it?

Comment: You should look in a dictionary before asking here.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, we're awfully pleased to see you.

Comment: No. It's a British usage and a bit slangy.  It's not surprising if an American English speaker hasn't encountered it.

Comment: @GregLee - The term is quite well known in the US.

Comment: Look up "awe", the consider that "awful" can mean "causing one to be filled with awe".

Comment: @Greg Lee I remember the Popeye scene: _Popeye_ ... 'Gorsh, you're awful pretty!' // _Olive Oyl_ ... 'Oooh, you're pretty awful yourself!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Awful**' has a variety of meanings.

The meanings are diverse and the phrase itself is used sometimes sarcastically so it is difficult to classify the saying into one particular pigeon hole.

If I say to someone 'you don't look well, you look just like your passport photo, you look *awful*' then it is definitely not a compliment. But I can also say 'my, you look awfully well'.

The [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awfully+well&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawfully%20well%3B%2Cc0) indicates that its usage has declined severely since the 1920s.
In some ways, the modern use of 'awesome' has taken over from 'awful'. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awesome&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawesome%3B%2Cc0) of awesome shows the opposite usage to 'awfully well'.

**Definition :**

> 1 :extremely disagreeable or objectionable awful food awful behavior an awful experience
>   2 informal :exceedingly great —used as an intensive an awful lot of money
>   3 :inspiring awe
>   … the presence of Nature in all her awful loveliness. —George Eliot
>   4 :filled with awe: such as
>   a :deeply respectful or reverential
>   b obsolete :afraid, terrified

**Use of awful as an adverb and an adjective :**

> Many grammarians take issue with the senses of awful and awfully that do not convey the etymological connection with awe.
>   However, senses 1 and 2 of the adjective were used in speech and casual writing by the late 18th century.

⟨ it is an awful while since you have heard from me —John Keats (letter) ⟩

⟨ there was an awful crowd —Sir Walter Scott (letter) ⟩

⟨ this is an awful thing to say to oil painters —William Blake ⟩

> Adverbial use of awful as an intensifier began to appear in print in the early 19th century, as did the senses of awfully corresponding to senses 1 and 2 of the adjective. Both adverbs remain in widespread use.

⟨ a sad state of affairs and awful tough on art —H. L. Mencken ⟩

⟨ the awfully rich young American —Henry James ⟩

⟨ decided to play it so awfully safe —A. M. Schlesinger born 1917 ⟩

All quotes from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awful)

Answer (score 4):

***Awfully*** is being used in accordance with OED sense 3. (senses 1 and 2, are actually opposites, both deriving from a communication of "awe", but the first meaning "in a dreadful, terrible way", the second "commanding reverence, and sublimely majestical".)

But sense 3 is quite different - a simple intensifier, used in polite society, in Britain, and perhaps elsewhere, to mean "very" or "especially". It tends to be associated with excessively polite, and well-to-do people, and can be used as a way of satirising such - "they are an awfully awfully nice family".

> 3. slang.  [Compare Greek δεινῶς awfully, exceedingly.] As simple intensive: very, exceedingly, extremely; (also) very badly.>
>
> 1816   J. Pickering Vocab. 42   A perverse, ill-natured child, that
>   disobeys his parents, would be said to behave awfully.*
>
> [1830   T. P. Thompson in Westm. Rev. Jan. 255   He will have made an
>   awfully bad choice if he comes to be sentenced to be hanged.]
>
> 1859   J. Lang Wanderings in India 154   In the way of
>   money-making..he is awfully clever.
>
> 1878   W. Black Green Pastures ii. 15   You'll be awfully glad to get
>   rid of me.
>
> 1885   N.E.D. at Awfully   Mod. It was awfully jolly!

- I do not think the 1816 example belongs to this sense 3, and is here in error. It belongs with sense 1, in my view.

I don't believe it fits the definition of an *oxymoron* which rhetorical figure conveys opposites in the same phrase to achieve emphasis, e.g "a living death".

Comment: Great explanation of awful as an intensifier!  I agree with your assessment of "awfully good" not being an oxymoron, except in the sense of wordplay, which might actually explain the attractiveness of that particular combination.

Comment: The [basic definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awe) of "awe" is *an emotion variously combining dread, veneration, and wonder that is inspired by authority or by the sacred or sublime*.  "Awful", being a simple contraction of "awe full", carries the same possibility of being either dreadful or wonderful.  There's nothing particularly "two faced" about the term -- it's simply used to express both extremes.

Comment: @Hot Licks I'd say that you're well into the etymological fallacy there. _Awful_ has by no means the same distribution as _awesome_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The two words have gone in opposite directions, true.  And so, as you say, the "distribution" of  meanings (if you were to count them up somehow using Ngram or wherever) has diverged.  But both words still carry both meanings, and have from the beginning.

Comment: 'The basic definition' ... 'aweful. being a simple contraction ...' is disingenuous. Relevant is _the most common and hence the default sense_. And 'awful' and 'awfully [_used before an adjective_]' do not have the same default sense (intercategorially adjusted).